# Ребята помогите решить проблему TorSharp

Tags: c#, websokets

Ребята помогите решить проблему у меня очень плохо с C# не судите строго.

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/joelverhagen/TorSharp

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var t = new TestToor();
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        try
        {
            t.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End");


        Console.Read();
    }


}

class TestToor
{

    public bool Start()
    {
        VirtualDesktopToolRunner().Wait();
        return true;
    }

    public async Task VirtualDesktopToolRunner()
    {
        var settings = new TorSharpSettings
        {
            TorSocksPort = 9150,
            PrivoxyPort = 8118,
            ExtractedToolsDirectory = @"\bin\ExtractedTools",
            ZippedToolsDirectory = @"\bin\ZippedTools",
            ToolRunnerType = ToolRunnerType.VirtualDesktop
        };

        using (var proxy = new TorSharpProxy(settings))
        {
            await new TorSharpToolFetcher(settings, new HttpClient()).FetchAsync();
            await proxy.ConfigureAndStartAsync();

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8118);

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                // Get the stream associated with the response.
                System.IO.Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                var html = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(html);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю ошибка и за того что тор не успевает подключится но я так и не нашел пример с ожиданием инициализации всех инструментов.
Помогите примером пожалуйста.

Comment: А какая ошибка? Вы забыли её привести в вопросе.